# Celery receives tasks from rabbitmq, but not executing them

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Django project and have setup Celery + RabbitMQ to do heavy tasks asynchronously. When I call the task, RabbitMQ admin shows the task, Celery prints that the task is received, but the task is not executed.

Here is the task's code:

```
@app.task
def dummy_task():
    print("I'm Here")
    User.objects.create(username="User1")
    return "User1 Created!"
```

In this view I send the task to celery:

```
def task_view(request):
      result = dummy_task.delay()
      return render(request, 'display_progress.html', context={'task_id': result.task_id})
```

I run celery with this command:

```
$ celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=2 --without-gossip
```

This is output of running Celery:

> -------------- celery@DESKTOP-8CHJOEG v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
> --- ***** -----
> -- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0 2022-08-22 10:10:04
>
> - *** --- * ---
> - ** ---------- [config]
> - ** ---------- .> app:         proj:0x23322847880
> - ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://navid:**@localhost:5672//
> - ** ---------- .> results:
> - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
>   -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
>   --- ***** -----  -------------- [queues]
>   .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
>
> [tasks]   .proj.celery.debug_task   .
> entitymatching.tasks.create_and_learn_machine   .
> entitymatching.tasks.dummy_task
>
> [2022-08-22 10:10:04,068: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to
> amqp://navid:**@127.0.0.1:5672// [2022-08-22 10:10:04,096:
> INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors [2022-08-22
> 10:10:04,334: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 6864 calling
> self.run() [2022-08-22 10:10:04,335: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child
> process 12420 calling self.run() [2022-08-22 10:10:05,134:
> INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone [2022-08-22 10:10:05,142:
> WARNING/MainProcess]
> C:\Users\Navid\PycharmProjects\proj\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:203:
> UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a  memory
> leak, never use this setting in production environments!   warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
>
> [2022-08-22 10:10:05,142: INFO/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-8CHJOEG
> ready. [2022-08-22 10:10:05,143: INFO/MainProcess] Task
> entitymatching.tasks.dummy_task[97f8a2eb-0006-4d53-ba6a-7b9f8649c84a]
> received [2022-08-22 10:10:05,144: INFO/MainProcess] Task
> entitymatching.tasks.dummy_task[17190479-0784-46b1-8dc6-870ead41e9c6]
> received [2022-08-22 10:11:36,384: INFO/MainProcess] Task
> proj.celery.debug_task[af3d633f-7b9a-4441-b375-9ce217a40ab3]
> received

But "I'm Here" is not printed, and User1 is not created.

RabbitMQ shows that there are 3 "unack" messages in the queue:
[image]

Comment: could you start celery with -E and see whats the output?

Comment: Please provide a little more information about the celery config in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not provide enough info although I think you have problem with your worker pools.

try adding

```
--pool=solo
```

at the end of your run command.
it will be like

```
celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=2 --without-gossip --pool=solo
```

although on production I recommend using gevent as your pool.

```
celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=2 --without-gossip --pool=gevent
```